# Angular ng-show not working in IE7/8

Tags: css, ajax, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, angularjs

I'm attempting to conditionally show/hide two divs using ng-show with a boolean value in $scope, based on when an AJAX call has completed. Basically, with the following layout:

```
<div id="div1" ng-show="!loadingData">
   <!--Some markup here-->
</div>
<div id="loadingMessage" ng-show="loadingData">
   Loading...
</div>
```

The function provoking the change contains the following:

```
$scope.loadingData=true;

var promise = dao.doAjaxGet("url");

promise.then(function(data){
  //Hide loading message
  $scope.loadingData=false;
});
```

The AJAX call is operating correctly, and this works fine in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, but not the two versions of IE that we are required to support - IE7 and IE8. The loading message stays hidden and div1 stays visible regardless of what status the call is in. Can anyone advise on this?

Comment: Can you put a `{{loadingData}}` and see whether the values are getting updated?

Comment: You're right, the value doesn't appear to be being applied. Further investigation shows similar behaviour in Chrome, though more sporadically. Why would that be?

Comment: Not affected by $scope.$apply() either.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `console.log` in your controller, get rid of it. It helped to get things working in IE8 e.g. ng-hide

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this is caching related. Chrome and IE both cache ajax calls after the first call. I've managed to resolve the problem in chrome by introducing `cache:false` into the ajax call configuration but this seems to have no effect in IE. If anybody has further information on this, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully working Angular ie7 template.  Ues a very old Angular, but works

My HTML File
    https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // IE7 fix   for missing  
        if (!window.console) {
            var console = {
                log: function() {},
                warn: function() {},
                error: function() {},
                time: function() {},
                timeEnd: function() {}
            }
        }
    </script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.2/json2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/es5.shim/4.5.7/es5-shim.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>

<script>
    /**
   * Main AngularJS Web Application
   */
    var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
    app.controller('MyPageCtrl', pageController);

    function pageController($scope) {

        $scope.languages = [
            { 'Id': 1, 'Name': 'French' },
            { 'Id': 1, 'Name': 'German' },
        ];
    };

</script>
</head>
 <body ng-controller="MyPageCtrl">

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <select name="languagesDropDown" id="languagesDropDown" class="form-control" style="width: 200px;">
        <option ng-repeat="language in languages" value="{{language.Id}}">{{language.Name}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue of `ng-show` not working in Internet Explorer.

The [official ngShow AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) mentions about this, and provides a few workarounds for this.

(I'll copy-paste the text mentioned in that link, in case that link has expired or is not working for some reason)

> When using `ngShow` and / or `ngHide` to toggle between elements, it
> can happen that both the element to show and the element to hide are
> visible for a very short time.
>
> This usually happens when the `ngAnimate` module is included, but no
> actual animations are defined for `ngShow` / `ngHide`. Internet
> Explorer is affected more often than other browsers.
>
> There are several way to mitigate this problem:
>
> - Disable animations on the affected elements.
> - Use `ngIf` or `ngSwitch` instead of `ngShow` / `ngHide`.
> - Use the special CSS selector `ng-hide.ng-hide-animate` to set `{display: none}` or similar on the affected elements.
> - Use `ng-class="{'ng-hide': expression}` instead of instead of `ngShow` / `ngHide`.
> - Define an animation on the affected elements.

The second suggestion (replacing `ng-show` with `ng-if`) worked for me. So in your case, you could consider using this -

```html
<div id="div1" ng-if="!loadingData">
  <!--Some markup here-->
</div>
<div id="loadingMessage" ng-if="loadingData">
  Loading...
</div>
```